# MySQL DELETE record is not working in vb

Tags: mysql, vb6

I am trying to delete selected record from my database which uses MySQL and Visual Basic 6 but its not working even no error I am getting in it. Here is my code for connection and also for button click

```
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public cn As New ADODB.Connection
Public sql As String
Dim dbpath As String

Sub main()
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With rs
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
.LockType = adLockOptimistic
End With

dbpath = "DSN=RetailPOS;"

On Error GoTo errhandler
With cn
    .Open dbpath
    '.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    MDIMAIN.Show
End With
'cn.Open dbpath
  Exit Sub

errhandler:
  MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description, _
  vbCritical
End Sub
```

button click code

```
Private Sub RmvBtn_Click()
    If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
    sql = "DELETE FROM tbluserinfo WHERE UserGroup = '" & Txt(3).Text & "'"
    cn.Execute (sql)
    MsgBox "The selected user was successfully deleted!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, ShowProductLabel
End Sub
```

Comment: What data type is UserGroup? What's the value of Txt(3).Text when you're testing? If UserGroup is numeric then you don't need the single quotes around the value. If UserGroup is text are you making sure Txt(3).Text doesn't have any white space that's causing the query to fail to find the value? Also if UserGroup is text, are you using a collation that's case sensitive?

Comment: UserGroup is numeric i.e. **int(5)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since UserGroup is numeric you should use

```
sql = "DELETE FROM tbluserinfo WHERE UserGroup = " & Txt(3).Text
```

You would also validate Txt(3).Text before calling the query. If it's empty then  you will end up with the following query which will throw an error.

```
DELETE FROM tbluserinfo WHERE UserGroup =
```

You should also check to make sure Txt(3).Text is numeric. Adding Trim() inside of IsNumeric() will catch a blank string because it won't be numeric.

```
If Not IsNumeric(Trim(Txt(3).Text)) Then
    'Tell the user and don't run the query
End If
```